# Greyed out section in Squarespace

Tags: background, overlay, squarespace, sections

HELP ME please.

When I create a new section within the portfolio part of my Squarespace website, it is greyed out. See link below. I can still add content to the section. As you can see there is a 'BACK' button and variations of background with either an image or plain colour. But why is there a white/grey overlay on the section?

If I move the section up then the image gallery comes down into the second position, and has the grey overlay. So it seems it's the second section position which has the problem. If I create another section below the second one it's completely fine as well.

I hope this is an easy one to fix.
thanks!

https://www.regardsfromyourfuture.com/future-paintings/project-one-44zcm-57lgb-6glfy-p2f7c-nbdk9-76lc2-zh5z9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is happening due to the following rule that is within your [Custom CSS / CSS Editor](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545567-Using-the-CSS-Editor):

```
  .page-section:nth-child(2) {
    background: #000 !important;
    filter: opacity(30%);
  }
```

That rule was likely written specifically for a different page, but was not written such that it only applies to said page. You'll want to examine your other pages to see if any page is benefiting from that rule, whereby the second section of the page has a lower opacity. If I were to guess, I'd say it's a section on a page that only has a background image with no content.

If there is no other page that benefits from the rule, you can simply delete it from your CSS.

On the other hand, if there is a page (or set of pages) that benefits from the rule, you would want to edit the rule so that it is specific to a single page (or set of pages) by adding the collection ID classes to the beginning of the rule.

Comment: Problem solved. You are an absolute legend! 

You're spot on with the code and explanation. I located and deleted the code which didn't add any value to the site.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Done :)
I can't cast a vote (yet), but feedback has been recorded.